# Unable to access ASP.NET Page inside a folder

Tags: asp.net

I am using `ASP.NET/C#`.

In my menu I have this `li` item

```
<li><a href="/Deposits/DepositsInterest.aspx">Update Deposit Interest</a></li>
```

But when I try to click on the `a` tag it just gives me this error

```
Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.
```

Can anyone just point me as to what might be missing here?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Problem doesn't seems in that link, Bug should be there where you are using `..`.

Comment: @yogi I am not quite getting your point.

Comment: try <li><a href="../Deposits/DepositsInterest.aspx">Update Deposit Interest</a></li>

Comment: @BizApps Martin's answer was the issue for me.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be caused by the DepositInterest.aspx page that you are navigating to. Are there any javascript/CSS files liked on that page or in the master page? If so you might want to check out that they are linked correctly.

[Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401703/cannot-use-a-leading-to-exit-above-the-top-directory)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1019849.aspx

Comment: It turned out to be what you suggested.I was linking to some scripts on my master page with ../Scripts/SomeScript.js.Thanks a lot.

Comment: :) Your very first answer on SO and you were spot on .Way to go.

Answer (score 0):

link should starts with tilde which represent root of your site or mention  your complete address

```
<li><a href="~/Deposits/DepositsInterest.aspx" runat="server" >Update Deposit Interest</a></li>
     // or type complete address 
<li><a href="YourSite/Deposits/DepositsInterest.aspx">Update Deposit Interest</a></li>
 //             or use asp.net hyperlink
 <li> <asp:HyperLink id="hl1"                  
              NavigateUrl="~/Deposits/DepositsInterest.aspx"
              Text="Hyperlink"
              Target="_new"
              runat="server"/> </li>
```

**Updated answer:**
If you are adding hyperlinks dynamically then add them as:

```
 MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();
    mi.NavigateUrl = "~/Deposits/DepositsInterest.aspx";
    mi.Text = "MY hyperlink";
    Menu1.Items.Add(mi);
    Menu1.DataBind();
```

Comment: You can't use `~` in a client side HTML link make it `runat="server"`.

Comment: @Waqar Thanks for the help , but now I am getting resource couldnot be found error

Comment: @WaqarJanjua When I click the link on my menu item it gives the error  /CwizBankApp/Deposits/DepositsInterest.aspx could not be found

Comment: @WaqarJanjua Yeah My page is inside Deposits folder which is under the root CwizBankApp

Comment: @freebird and what code ( anchor or hyperlink ) in your listitem you are using now

Comment: @WaqarJanjua I am using anchor tag.

Comment: @freebird see updated ans. also are you using Asp:Menu control ? plz show your menu code too