# Global.asax Routing not working with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I've this kind of routes bellow:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("EFICDUARTE_PRODUTOS", "produto/{nomeouid}", "~/produto.aspx");
```

And then when i try to call this route (url) it gives me this error:

> **Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.**

In any case i'm **NOT** using **../** to routing

Comment: How do you call the route? Does it work if you type it directly to the browser?

Comment: And answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262271/cannot-use-a-leading-to-exit-above-the-top-directory

Comment: i said i didn't use ../ that question does not applies @Sami

Comment: it does not work in any way i call

Comment: @PTLearner - Which route\Url you are trying? You said " i try to call `this` route (url)" but you didn't mentioned the url.

Comment: http://eficduarte.azurewebsites.net/produto/1

Comment: Does it work if you call the .aspx directly without routing? If not, the problem is propably in the markup. Can you post that too?

Comment: works fine with .aspx!

Comment: Does the routing work without the parameter?