# Root directory master page with sub-folder's child page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can we use Master Page that is in the root directory for child pages those are in sub-folder?
If yes then how? please let me know

I know its duplicate of this question
[Cannot use a leading ../ to exit above the top directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262271/cannot-use-a-leading-to-exit-above-the-top-directory)

but that is related to image file and i am getting error in master page's path that is not working here and I didn't get my answer there because I did this and got an error below

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.

this is what I have tried

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="..\Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChildPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="IMS.SubFolder.ChildPage" %> 

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChildPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="IMS.ChildPage" %>

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChildPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="IMS.SubFolder.ChildPage" %> 

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChildPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="IMS.ChildPage" %>

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="../Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChildPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="IMS.ChildPage" %>
```

Comment: Yes, we can. How have to assigned the Master property? Your path leads to outside of the website, that's what the error message tells you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262271/cannot-use-a-leading-to-exit-above-the-top-directory

Comment: @TimSchmelter I tried this answer too. but getting the same error

Comment: What you have tried? You don't show what you have tried. We can't help to fix it

Comment: this is what i have tried
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="..\Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChildPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="IMS.SubFolder.ChildPage" %>

Comment: You could use the `~` to get the root of you app, then navigate to the master, for example: `MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Main.Master"`

Comment: Still getting same error