# Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory. Error

Tags: c#

```
`Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.`

`[HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.]
   System.Web.Util.UrlPath.ReduceVirtualPath(String path) +9985452
   System.Web.Util.UrlPath.Reduce(String path) +50
   System.Web.Util.UrlPath.Combine(String appPath, String basepath, String relative) +217
   System.Web.UI.Control.ResolveClientUrl(String relativeUrl) +266
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink.RenderAttributes(HtmlTextWriter writer) +74
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +41
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +128
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +21
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +128
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +13
   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +12
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +128
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1303
`
```

My project was working fine and now i do not know what happen, every time i navigate it gives me the error.

I tried using the full link 
1. `<a class="nav-link" href=" http://localhost:64406/Test/Product.aspx">Add Products</a>`

2. `<a class="nav-link" href="../../Test/Product.aspx">Add Products</a>`
3. `<a class="nav-link" href="../Test/Product.aspx">Add Products</a>`
4. `<a class="nav-link" href="~/Test/Product.aspx">Add Products</a>`
5. `<a class="nav-link" href="Test/Product.aspx">Add Products</a>`

Nothing works.

I searched everywhere to try and find the solution but nothing solved my problem. also visited this link [Cannot use a leading ../ to exit above the top directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262271/cannot-use-a-leading-to-exit-above-the-top-directory) but it could not solve my problem.

Comment: When you say "nothing works" - what errors are you getting, for say: <a class="nav-link" href="~/Test/Product.aspx">Add Products</a>

Comment: error 404 `Requested URL: /~/Test/Product.aspx`

Comment: http://localhost:64406/~/Test/Product.aspx

Comment: Please could you update the question with your project structure.

Comment: What do you mean "Project Structure", so i can get it for you

Comment: From your question, it looks like you have a Test folder in the root, but I suspect that maybe that doesn't align with the structure of your site

Answer (score 0):

This will help everyone who struggled to get the solution for this problem, I solved this problem by replacing all the links `<a class="nav-link" href="../Test/Product.aspx">Add Products</a>` WITH `<a class="nav-link" href="/Test/Product.aspx">Add Products</a>`

This includ all the CSS and Js links `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>`

Don't just replace 1 link, replace all the links in your MasterPage.